# Copy all files with extension to appropriate folder

Tags: bash, pdf, copy-paste

I am new to creating .sh files (and bash scripting) and I am trying to create a script that would read, rename an copy files to a folder with appropriate name, but do not know how to go around this. I was hoping one of you could point me to the right direction.

This is my start (still some errors in it)

```
 #!/bin/bash
for i in 'find /temp_pdf -type f | xargs grep *.pdf'; #loop for findg all .pdf files residing in temp_pdf
do
#1234 invoice.pdf
directory=${i:0:4}; # read the first 4 chars of the file name
#cp 1234 invoice.pdf /copy/1234*
cp $i /copy/$directory*; #copy the the file to /copy/xxxx* folder
done;
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help, there is just one thing that I am wondering about. How can I copy or move the file to a folder which I only know the starting 4 chars and wildcard

Comment: directory=${i:0:4}; # read the first 4 chars of the file name

cp $i /copy/$directory*; #copy the the file to /copy/xxxx* folder

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easier:

```
$ find . -name \*.pdf -exec cp ...
```

And if you would like more information [look here](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/using_exec_option_and_xargs_in_find.shtml).

**EDIT**

More simply:

```
$ cp **/*.pdf target_directory
```

Comment: This is missing the part where the first 4 characters of the file name are used in the output directory.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd like to do something like this:

```
SOURCE="./temp_pdf"
DESTINATION="copy"
mkdir -p "$DESTINATION"

for i in `find "$SOURCE" -type f | grep 'pdf$'`; do #loop for findg all .pdf files residing in temp_pdf
    cp -v "$i" "$DESTINATION"  #copy the the file to DESTINATION folder (verbose)
done
```

I'm not sure that you wanted to use a global destination folder. If you want to do that, you can do it inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If i have .ext-files in a directory that i want to place in another directory while altering the file name i would do this:

```
for file in path/to/dir1/*.ext; do 
  mv $file path/to/dir2/new_pref${file}new_suf
done
```

your can put this in a file called ren.sh then

```
$ chmod u+x ren.sh
$ ./ren.sh
```

`new_pref` could be some string, `new_suf` could be something like `.alt` or or .new. If you want to remove parts of the file name use `${file%*id}` or `${file##*id}` for removing stuff in the beginning or end of file-name respectively, up until, and including, `id`. Where `id` is a reoccurring part of the file name like `.`, `_` or `-` or something. Google for parameter expansion for more detail or look at 'man bash' under parameter expansion.